# Is the "Hulked Out Heroes" storyline canon?

Tags: marvel, thor-marvel, canon, the-incredible-hulk

I haven't read the storyline yet, but I have seen some rather compelling bits and pieces of it, and based on what I have seen, I really want this to be canonical, not a "What If?" type of alternative universe deal.

[image: Hulked Out Thor about to smash Red Hulk]

Is the "Hulked Out Heroes" storyline canonical?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they are canon - they are part of the "World War Hulks"(*) storyline, which starts at the end of the "Fall of the Hulks" story. MODOK and the Intelligencia has been trying to use Red Hulk create an army of Hulks for AIM. Deadpool breaks Red Hulk out of his containment, and unleashes the transformation on a bunch of nearby heroes, including himself, Thing, Spider-Man, Human Torch, Thor, and others.

[image: Hulkpool!]

These events lead directly into the World War Hulks storyline.

The heroes do not stay Hulked-up for long; the radiation is killing them, and they have to get it fixed pretty quickly. The Marvel Wikia has a [comprehensive list](http://marvel.wikia.com/World_War_Hulks) of the issues that include parts of this storyline:

- World War Hulks #1
- Incredible Hulk #609-#611
- Hulk Vol 2 #22-#24
- World War Hulks: Hulked-Out Heroes #1-#2
- World War Hulks: Spider-Man & Thor #1-#2
- World War Hulks: Wolverine & Captain America #1-#2

Footnotes:

(*) - This is not to be confused with the far more famous "World War Hulk" (singular) event, which happened many years earlier.

Comment: Great answer.  I ran out of upvotes, but I'll give you one later.

Comment: I'm curious since the radiation was killing the other heroes they needed to be changed back, but would deadpool need to be changed back since he cannot die, due to his healing factor and the fact that Thanos cursed him so he cannot die.

Comment: I'm not sure what happened to Deadpool; many of these aren't available digitally so I can't go back and check.

Comment: The Thanos thing was written out a while ago I think